# Problem Importing a JS Function in my Typescript Project

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am making a project using ThreeJS and trying to import a js function that adds a ASCII Effect to the renderer but no matter how I do it I seem to get errors. I've tried several syntaxes and changing the TS config but no luck.

Edit: Just realised I should clarify, I downloaded the AsciiEffect function as a js file from the github repo directly so I am trying to import a single function from the file I downloaded "AsciiEffect.js" to my main TS file "main.ts". I am not importing from the ThreeJS dependency, as it is not a part of the package itself apparently.

TS Config File

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ESNext",
    "useDefineForClassFields": true,
    "module": "commonJS",
    "lib": ["ESNext", "DOM"],
    "moduleResolution": "Node",
    "strict": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "allowJs": true
  },
  "include": ["src"]
}
```

currently I am trying to import like this

```
import './style.css'
import * as THREE from 'three';
import {AsciiEffect} from './effects/AsciiEffect.js'
```

and exporting from AsciiEffect.js like this

```
export {AsciiEffect}
```

which gives me this error in the browser
Uncaught SyntaxError: Export 'AsciiEffect' is not defined in module

I have tried using other syntaxes but had no luck, this is my first project attempting to use typescript and I actually expected the effect to be inside the ThreeJS dependency. I tried redoing what I have so far in JS but get the same error. The project was created using Vite if that helps at all. Its just a default TS project with no framework.

Comment: I get this error instead if i do that. \n

Module '"/home/connor/lighthouse/portfolio-site/src/effects/AsciiEffect"' has no default export. Did you mean to use 'import { AsciiEffect } from "/home/connor/lighthouse/portfolio-site/src/effects/AsciiEffect"' instead?ts(2613)

Comment: Bad export, you are exporting an object.
`export AsciiEffect`

Comment: This is what I get now on the export ---
Declaration or statement expected.ts(1128)

Comment: Yes, now just create a file `declarations.d.ts` in the root of the project, and paste in:
`declare module "path/to/the/module";`
And you are done. You have to tell TS explicitely when you import from non TS modules.

Comment: Thank you! I think that did it, still have a couple things to work out but that should get me started now that its imported properly.

Comment: I added the comment as an answer, feel free to mark as solved if it fixed your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a bad export, export the function like this:
`export AsciiEffect`
Then TS compiler will complain that it doesn't recognize that module, since it's a `.js` module and not a TS one, so you need to add  custom moudle declaration:

1. If you don't already have a `*.d.ts` file in the root of your project, create a file called `declarations.d.ts`.
2. Inside of it add this line: `declare module "path/to/the/module";`

This way you are telling TS that that is a legit module to import from.