# Exporting methods when publishing an npm package

Tags: javascript, typescript, npm, node-modules, package.json

I'm trying to publish an npm esm module that exports [two methods](https://github.com/BrycePearce/CsvToFlatfile/blob/main/src/index.ts). When the module is installed and imported I want the user to be able to import it like:

```js
import { convertCsvToWorkbook, createFlatfile } from 'csvtoflatfile';
console.log(convertCsvToWorkbook, createFlatfile);

// or

import csvtoflatfile from 'csvtoflatfile';
console.log(csvtoflatfile)
```

It works locally in [my demo](https://github.com/BrycePearce/CsvToFlatfile/blob/main/src/demo/example.ts#L2) but when installing the module from npm I get an error: Module '"csvtoflatfile"' has no exported member 'convertCsvToWorkbook'.ts(2305)

[image]

This import does sort of work, but I can't actually seem to access the methods on it:

[image]

---

I'm exporting the methods individually [here in my index.ts](https://github.com/BrycePearce/CsvToFlatfile/blob/main/src/index.ts#L52), which looks like:

```
export const convertCsvToWorkbook = () => {}
export const createFlatfile= () => {}

export default {
    convertCsvToWorkbook,
    createFlatfile,
};
```

How can I fix my exports so that they can be properly imported when downloaded through npm?

Comment: So this seems to work fine when imported into a native JS file, so your issue might be with TypeScript. I would try changing all of the [imports here](https://github.com/BrycePearce/CsvToFlatfile/blob/6a5caa2f908d702f34c7e797f1e03c074604dafa/src/index.ts#L2C1-L8) to be the proper `.ts` extensions. And confirm other imports are using the proper extension and try it again. Otherwise not sure...

EDIT: You may also try updating your type definitions [here](https://github.com/BrycePearce/CsvToFlatfile/blob/6a5caa2f908d702f34c7e797f1e03c074604dafa/%40types/index.d.ts#L1C1-L7C3)

Comment: thanks! Unfortunately with ESM importing the .js equivalent is required

Comment: See my edit, I wonder if your types are missing the functions and TS is complaining about that. Also this may be related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72065831/1514049

Comment: hm that is possible, I can try moving those types to the index.d.ts as well. I'll give that a shot, thanks!

Comment: unfortunately no luck, I exported both types and it produces an identical result to the initial post. This is a tough one!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the issue is from the typing setup on your `"types": "./@types/index.d.ts"` [`package.json`](https://github.com/BrycePearce/CsvToFlatfile/blob/main/package.json#L6) which points to a fixed type file which is supposed to be the generated one as you build the code.

Hence, I would suggest to remove this setup and TS will help you to look up your `index.d.ts` in the same your index file `dist/index.js`

Comment: This is correct, and you will have to revert the recent changes made to `index.d.ts` as there may be conflicts now.

Comment: unbelievable, I completely misunderstood how that worked. This fixed it, thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

```
// you are already exported as `named export` here
export const convertCsvToWorkbook = () => {}
export const createFlatfile= () => {}

// you don't to do `default export` here
export default {
    convertCsvToWorkbook,
    createFlatfile,
};
```

Comment: thanks! This was my first attempt, unfortunately it gives similar errors: Module '"csvtoflatfile"' has no exported member 'convertCsvToWorkbook'.ts